# sed find regex pattern then find next regex pattern (variable multi line) and replace

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to find a way to insert a string ' .sh' into a particular line in a text file using sed. The problem i have is that i only want to insert the string if a previous regex matches, it also has to support a variable number of lines between the 'name' and 'extension' tag and to be idempotent, so i can run it multiple times with only a single insertion of ' .sh' for the 'extension' tagged space separated list.

Here is a small snippet of the text file:-

```
    <name>gba</name>
    <fullname>Game Boy Advance</fullname>
    <manufacturer>Nintendo</manufacturer>
    <release>2001</release>
    <hardware>portable</hardware>
    <path>/storage/roms/gba</path>
    <extension>.gba .GBA .zip .ZIP .7z .7Z</extension>
```

so i want to change `<extension>.gba .GBA .zip .ZIP .7z .7Z</extension>` to `<extension>.gba .GBA .zip .ZIP .7z .7Z .sh</extension>` ONLY if the name tag is `<name>gba</name>`

This is the best i have come up with so far, but it has two problems, firstly subsequent executions of the code duplicate the insertion and secondly its for a fixed number of lines (6), which may not always be the case:-

`sed -i '/<name>gba<\/name>/{n;n;n;n;n;n;s/<\/extension>/ .sh<\/extension>/}' /tmp/test.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested with `GNU sed` (syntax might vary for other implementations):

```sh
sed '/<name>gba</,/<extension>/{/<extension>/{/\.sh/! s/<\/extension>/ .sh&/}}'
```

- `/<name>gba</,/<extension>/` this will match range of lines starting with a line containing `<name>gba<` and ending with a line containing `<extension>`

  - this is based on given sample, you can modify the regex if you need more robust matching condition
- `{}` helps to group commands to be executed only for the given matching conditions
- for such range of lines:

  - `/<extension>/` match only this line
  - `/\.sh/!` check if it *doesn't* have `.sh`
  - `s/<\/extension>/ .sh&/` add `.sh` for such lines

Answer (score 2):

In case you are ok with `awk`, could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '
/<name>/{ found="" }
/<name>gba<\/name>/{
  found=1
}
found && /<extension>/ && !/\.sh</{
  sub(/<\//," .sh&")
  found=""
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                     ##Starting awk program from here.
/<name>/{ found="" }
/<name>gba<\/name>/{      ##Searching string <name>gba</name>
  found=1                 ##Setting found to 1 here.
}
found && /<extension>/ && !/\.sh</{   ##Checking found is set and <extension> is found in line then do following.
  sub(/<\//," .sh&")      ##Substituting </ with space .sh and matched value in current line.
  found=""                ##Nullifying found here.
}
1                         ##Printing current line here.
'  Input_file             ##Mentioning Input_file here.
```

Comment: thanks!, i am fine with awk, if i execute the code above and write it out to the same name as the input file  (using ```/tmp/test.txt > tmp && mv tmp /tmp/test.txt```) and then re-run i see a duplicate insertion of ' .sh' in the extension tagged list, so it doesn't seem to be idempotent.

Comment: @binhex, sure, I have added 1 more condition which will only do replacements when `.sh` is not present, kindly do check it once and let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: thanks RavinderSingh13 your revision works!, i think i am going to have to give the accepted answer to @Sundeep for his sed only solution, but i do really appreciate your response and breakdown of the code.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/<name>gba<\/name>/{:a;n;/<\/extension>/!ba;/\.sh/!s/<\/extension/ .sh&/}' file
```

Focus on a line containing `<name>gba</name>`.

Print the current line, fetch the next and if that line does not contain `</extension>`, repeat.

Otherwise, if the current line does not contain `.sh` already, prepend it to the above string.